# Should I make my static factory method final?

Tags: java, final

I'm reading 'Effective Java' and I don't see any use of final when he's talking about static factory method.However, as we expect each static factory method create a specific instance and we don't expect any new behavior, shouldn't we make them final as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are inherently final, because they can't be overridden by subclasses.